# Ant xmltask <attr> creates an empty "xmlns" attribute value

Tags: xml, ant, xmltask

I have an XML file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<CustomObject>
</CustomObjects>
```

I apply the XMLTask attr in the following way:

```
<attr path="/CustomObject" attr="xmlns" value="test"/>
```

I expect the XML file to now include the attribute `xmlns` with the value "test"

The actual output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="">
</CustomObjects>
```

Has anyone ran into this problem before? or has any indication as what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like xmltask cannot create attributes with the name `xmlns`. This appears to be a known bug: [#8 attr name="xmlns" does not work on Mac](https://sourceforge.net/p/xmltask/bugs/8/).

In XML, `xmlns` is a reserved attribute name. It refers to the default namespace. For more about default namespaces, see [Namespace Defaulting](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) in the Namespaces in XML 1.0 W3C Recommendation.

As an alternative solution, consider using [XSLT to add a namespace to the root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981488/how-can-i-add-namespaces-to-the-root-element-of-my-xml-using-xslt).