# How to generate custom tag names and namespaces in xml using apache camel

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, bindy

I'm trying to transform pipe delimited string data to xml using camel bindy. But it is generating the tags along with the class name. Also I would like to add namespace to my tags.

I tried to use Camel process to generate custom tag, it's not working.

***ConverterRoute.java***

```
    private static final String SOURCE_INPUT_PATH = "file://inbox?fileName=3000.txt";

    private static final String SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH = "file://outbox?fileName=itemfile.xml";

    public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext context) throws Exception {
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                try {
                    DataFormat bindyFixed = new BindyCsvDataFormat(PartInboundIFD.class);

                    NameSpace nameSpace = new NameSpace("PART_INB_IFD","https://apache.org.com");
                    from(SOURCE_INPUT_PATH).
                            unmarshal(bindyFixed).
                            marshal().
                            xstream().
                            to(SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***Pojo.java***

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\\|",skipField = true)
public class Pojo {

    @Link
    private ControlSegment CONTROL_SEGMENT;

}
```

***CamelComponent.java***

```
public class CamelConfig extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        try {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            ConverterRoute route = new ConverterRoute();
            route.addRoutesToCamelContext(context);
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            context.stop();
        } catch (Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***OUTPUT***
***Result.xml***

```
<list>
    <com.abc.domain.Pojo>
        <CONTROL__SEGMENT/>
            <TRNNAM>PART_TRAN</TRNNAM>
            <TRNVER>9.0</TRNVER>
    </com.abc.domain.Pojo>
</list>
```

Above posted is the output of the given transformation.In the first tag it is printing the tag name with whole package and class name(eg: com.abc.domain.Pojo).Also I'm trying to generate namespace its not generating that in my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can add an additional XSLT route (https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/xslt-component.html). 
Within the XSLT it's possible to transform the XML to your liking and add the correct namespaces ([How can I add namespaces to the root element of my XML using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981488/how-can-i-add-namespaces-to-the-root-element-of-my-xml-using-xslt))

Comment: That helped us to solve the namespace. But Can I generate individual xml instead list of xmls in the same output file ?